# Removing radicals from denominator

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

Is there an easy way to all remove radicals from a denominator?
I would like a function, say `RemRadsFromDenom` that, e.g., transforms
$\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{1+\sqrt{3}}$ to $-\frac{(1-\sqrt{3})^2}{2}$ and, e.g., $\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{1-\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}}$ to $\frac{7 - 2 \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5} + 2 \sqrt{15}}{11}$.

So when given a fraction containing radicals, I want ```RemRadsFromDenom`` to return an expression without any radicals in the denominator.

I feel there should be a built-in function to do this, but I haven't found anything in the documentation centre. There exits algorithms to achieve this result but before implementing those on my own I wondered if there isn't any built-in functionality that achieves the goal. This does seem like a standard thing that any CAS should be able to do.

All questions related to this one have answers that circumvent using such a function. Typically because some obvious simplification could be done, in which case FullSimplify could be used.

Comment: `FullSimplify`?

Comment: ```FullSimplify``` doesn't guarantee that the denominator in the result has no radicals.

Comment: Please give an example problem where `FullSimplify` does not work.

Comment: For example ```FullSimplify[(1 + Sqrt[3])/(1 - Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[5])]```. It is important to note that one can make ```FullSimplify``` work for this case as well but I would like a function that works for any case and guarantees that the result has no radicals in the denominator. 
Since I don't know the inner workings of ```FullSimplify``` I can't assume it will always do this

Comment: so what do you want for example $\frac{1-\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}}{1+\sqrt{3}}$ to transform to? It is better to give more examples than just one so one gets better idea of what is it you want. For the example you gave, it is easy to do what you want. `expr = (1 - Sqrt[3])/(1 + Sqrt[3]);
num = Numerator[expr]; den = Denominator[expr];
expr = Simplify[num^2]/Simplify[num*den]` but this will not work for all cases.

Comment: @Nasser, sorry the question was not very clear indeed. I changed it now. The thing is that there are algorithms to remove all radicals from a denominator and it is an operation that is often used in algebra so I would assume Mathematica must have some standard function to achieve the result. I just can't find anything...

Answer (score 2):

You haven't really given a lot of test cases, so it is hard to properly test our solutions.

```
RemRadsFromDenom[expr_] := 
 FullSimplify[expr, 
  ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 
      1000 Count[Denominator@Together@#, 
        Sqrt[_] | Surd[_, _] | _^Rational[_, _] | Root[__], All] &)]

testCases = {
  (1 + Sqrt[3])/(1 - Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[5]), 
  (1 - Sqrt[3])/(1 + Sqrt[3]), 
  (1 - 5^(1/3))/(2 - 6^(1/3) + 7^(1/5))
 };

RemRadsFromDenom /@ testCases
(* {
    1/11 (-2 + 4 Sqrt[3] + 5 Sqrt[5] + Sqrt[15]),  
    -2 + Sqrt[3], 
    (-1 + 5^(1/3)) Root[1 + 30 # + 420 #^2 + ... + 2889720 #^14 + 1064823 #^15&, 1, 0]
   } 
*)
```